# Load balancer F5 and sticky session

Tags: load-balancing, f5-big-ip, sticky-sessions

I have installed a web application on a clustered environment where the load is balanced by an F5 device. Unfortunately I do not know exactly its model, but hopefully this information is not necessary to answer my question.

We were trying to troubleshoot an issue with the session timeout, and I saw in the admin interface of the LB a parameter that specifies the "Persistence Timeout" for the stickiness of the session. 
For the web application to work, the load balancer should be configured to use sticky sessions, but this parameter was set to 8 minutes.

Does this mean that the stickiness of the session will time out after 8 minutes even if the user is not idle?

There was also another parameter in the admin console that was the "Session idle timeout". This is why I am thinking that the other parameter is a different timeout.

Comment: Have you read the F5 docs? I suspect that they'd have those options explained somewhere..

Comment: The problem is that I do not know the model of the F5. I searched their site but there are so many different models I none of them seems to have the two parameters that we found in the admin console.

Comment: If it's a LTM device, you can find the type via the webinterface: Device Management => Devices => click on the device, the Platform ID and Platform Name are shown there